# Solving for traffic flow density as a function of time and determining when it's no longer valid

Tags: partial-differential-equations, characteristics

So I'm working on the following problem.
When given an initial density of:

\begin{equation}
\rho(x,0)=
    \begin{cases}
        \frac{\rho_{max}}{4}, & x<0\\
        \rho_{max}, & 0 < x <x_0 \\
        \frac{\rho_{max}}{3}, & x > x_0
    \end{cases}  \\
\text{with the standard traffic wave equation being:}\\
\partial{\rho}_t +c(\rho)\partial{\rho}_x = 0
\end{equation}
I am told to assume a standard linear relationship, that is:
\begin{equation}
v(\rho) = v_0\frac{\rho_{max} - \rho}{\rho_{max}}\\
\text{Which implies:}\\
c(\rho) = v_0\frac{\rho_{max} - 2\rho}{\rho_{max}}
\end{equation}

I am also aware that when $x = 0$ we have $c(\rho) = x/t$ (this is from the characteristic curves being $X(t) = x_0+c(\rho_0(x_0))t$  ). Rearranging this gives me:
\begin{equation}
\rho = \frac{\rho_{max}}{2}(1-\frac{x}{v_0t})
\end{equation}
The bit I am stuck on is how do I use the information from the initial conditions to find a formula for the density that is valid for short times? I have looked at each individual case for the piecewise function and I'm not left with a density function, but I do have a suspicion that the $\rho_{max}$ terms will cause some interesting simplification.

I assume once I have this formula I could deduce when the solution is no longer valid too?

**Edit:** fixed the standard traffic wave equation.

I'm also adding the derivation for $v(\rho)$ to $c(\rho)$

If we start with:
\begin{equation}
\partial{\rho}_t +\partial{q}_x = 0\\
\text{Where}\\
\rho(x,t): \text{car density}\\
v(\rho): \text{car velocity}\\
q(x,t) = \rho v: \text{car flow rate}\\
\end{equation}
We can make some smart substitutions to get:
\begin{align}
\partial{\rho}_t +\partial{q}_x &= 0\\
&= \partial{\rho}_t +\partial{(v(\rho)\rho)}_x\\
&=\partial{\rho}_t +(v'(\rho)\rho +v(\rho))\partial{\rho}_x
\end{align}
Then $c(\rho)=v'(\rho)\rho +v(\rho)$ which is the kinematic wave speed.

When we substitute $v(\rho)$ into the above relation, we get
\begin{equation}
c(\rho) = v_0\frac{\rho_{max} - 2\rho}{\rho_{max}}
\end{equation}

Comment: @Gonçalo, I fixed the PDE and added the derivation for the second part of your question.

Comment: As written, of course, the equations require differentiability w.r.t. $x$.  What happens if you insert a thin layer (maybe a linear interpolation of density) between two regions of constant density?  Can you say how that situation evolves?